# can i get more granular ami events for app_fax?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

When sending a fax using spandsp/asterisk/app_fax, it would really be nice to see more granular status events being fired.

Right now, it just looks like AMI events are fired when the call is started and when the call finishes.  I'm looking to get more detailed info like "DIALING", "SENDING PAGE 1", etc.

Is there a way (either using the AMI or another method) to get this information?

I know it definitely exists somewhere, as I can see DEBUG statements with this information in the logs.  I can't (and don't want to) parse the log files, as the DEBUG statements don't really say which call they relate to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no
but nojee fax project did special patch for app_fax.c to give more verbosity.

probably u can create patch for app_fax.c to show needed info.